# Database (likely noSQL) with built in data retention features

Tags: database, nosql, storage, archive

What open source databases have features for automatic "aging out" of data, so that you can specify for how long a piece of data must be stored?

I.e. a set date or time on a piece of data, after which, the database is free to remove every trace of it.

Update:
I am more looking for an age out time of days to years, more than minutes or seconds. So a cache mechanism isn't exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Could an automatic out of hours batch job to delete out-of-date data be sufficient for your needs?

Comment: @beny23, yes indeed. It's just that this is such a fundamental problem waiting to be solved I thought that some databases might have support for this already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MongoDB has something in the new release 2.2, which may be of interest - [TTL Collections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/).

Collections expire by way of a special index that keeps track of insertion time in conjunction with a background mongod process that regularly removes expired documents from the collection. You can use this feature to expire data from replica sets and shard clusters.

It's pretty easy to create a TTL collection from the mongo shell -

`db.mycollection.ensureIndex( { "status": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )`

- Download 2.2rc0 [here](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) (release candidate, not quite production ready...there will be one more release candidate before the production build)
- Change Log [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER/fixforversion/11218)
- 2.2 release notes can be found [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.2/).

I can't speak for the other solutions.

Answer (score 6):

I think most of the noSql databases support this feature, but for example, cassandra has that feature:

http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/ddl/column_family.

Cassandra can be downloaded from here:

http://cassandra.apache.org/

However If you are using such a db **solely for the expiry time**, consider using a cache, because of the fact it exactly fits what you are trying to do, especially if your time to live of objects is short. After all, purpose of a cache is 'as a container for objects you want to store temporary'. Most traditional caches are Key - Value caches/datastores, much like most NoSql databases.

While nosql databases like cassandra are generally very fast in retrieving data, you will find that most of them underperform if you constantly add and remove data as compared to traditional caches, and add an additional filesystem and/or network overhead. If you find that what you do need is actually a cache, there are a few I can recommend.

http://ehcache.org/

> Is a non-distributed cache with a very simple api

http://www.jboss.org/infinispan/

> is a distributed in-memory cache/K,V store

With caches, however, you are restricted in how much you can store, as by default they are in-memory. Most of them have the option to store data on filesystems as well, but if it comes to that, I would use a noSQL db.

Comment: Thanks. Updated question re: the cache stuff. +1 though.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what type of data you need to store. Is simple key-value store enough or you need document databse.

It is a common usage of cache. You can try EHCache, Hazelcast, Memcached etc. But theese are key-value stores mostly. There are several policies of removing data - the oldest, the least used etc. Theese are rather in-memory stores. If you need persistent K/V store with this feature try Redis.

I'f you're collecting time-based data for for example usage stats you might use RRD-type database which aggregates older data instead of removing it (makes day, week, month sums)

If you need more like a document database it seems that MongoDB supports simple document expiration (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/). CouchDB seems not to support this, however, you might run a timer task to remove old data.

Comment: +1, covering all the bases since I was not specific enough. Seems I am looking for Mongodb >= 2.2 or Redis, or similar.

Comment: Great, note that Mongodb is not similar to Redis :-)

Answer (score 2):

Couchbase offers TTL deletes using the memcached binary protocol to set the time to live. So you can store a data item, with a timestamp it should be deleted after (can be arbitrarily far in the future). When that time comes, Couchbase will delete the data item.

Here's an example of how to set a TTL from Ruby. There are examples in other languages if you prefer: http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-sdk-ruby-1.0/couchbase-sdk-ruby-getting-started-hello.html